# Microsoft Graph Application Manifest

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, restrict, web-app-manifest

I need advice: How to prevent any logins from persons outside the tenant organisation in a microsoft-graph web-app? I have to restrict the web-application only to my organisation/tenant. The Option ***availableToOtherTenants*** is already set to ***false***. Is there a best practice or HowToDo?

Comment: If it isn't defined to be a multitenant app, it will only be available to user accounts in the tenant where the app has been created.

Answer (score 0):

After you set the **availableToOtherTenants** to **false**, the users from other tenants should not able to sign-in the application unless those users have been invited by to your tenant.

And to limit the specific users we want to allow to access that app, we can enable the **User assignment required** feature:
[image]

Then we need to assign the users by **the users and groups** of the application under **Enterprise applications** before the users can access that application.

Comment: I registered my WebApp at **https://apps.dev.microsoft.com**... Created the app and already edited the app.manifest...and beyond the topic **tags** there is **availableToOtherTenents** set to **false**??? Do I have to register my WebApp in the AzureApps too? It's working fine and i can request the Microsoft-Graph successfully...???

Comment: If you were login to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ using the orgnization account, there are two kinds of apps we can register. One kind is **Converged applications**, and the other is **Azure AD only applications**. To limit the users from your organization, you should create **Azure AD only applications** instead of **Converged applications** which is used of V2.0 endpoint enable sign-in both for Microsoft Account and Organization Account. Also I suggest that you manage the app fro [Azure portal](portal.azure.com) if you doesn't want to use Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

Comment: What did you mean about registering the web app in Azure Apps? Both the app register on [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) or [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), can call the Microsoft Graph REST.

Comment: I found the error - i was using the URLs https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize and https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token - i changed this two URLs to https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant/oauth2/v2.0/authorize and everything is working as expected - only account from my tenant are able to login. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Based on the request URL, you were using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint. And to  limit the specific organization account to sign-in, replace the `common` with your organization tenant(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) about the `tenant` parameter).  Or you can register the app on Azure portal to use the original endpoint(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) for the protocols).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error - i was using the URLs https://login.microsoftonline.com/***common***/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
and https://login.microsoftonline.com/***common***/oauth2/v2.0/token - i changed this two URLs to https://login.microsoftonline.com/***my-tenant***/oauth2/v2.0/authorize and everything is working as expected - only account from my tenant are able to login. Sorry, my fault.